# Linear Transformation proof about one to one

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Qu. $\textbf{4}\quad$** Suppose that $S$, $T:V\to V$ are linear transformations of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, and suppose that the composition $ST:V\to V$ is invertible. Show that then $T$ is one-to-one, and deduce that $T$ is invertible. Show also that $S$ is invertible. Deduce that $ST$ is invertible if and only if $TS$ is invertible.

I first tried to show that T is one to one.

If $v_1, v_2$ are in $V$,

$T(v_1) = T(v_2)$

$T(v_1-v_2) = 0$

$v_1 - v_2$ is in kernel of $T$

Now I don't know what to do next?

Comment: If $T(v) = T(w)$ then $ST(v) = ST(w)$ hence $v=w$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\operatorname{Ker}(T) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(ST)$.  Also, once you deduce that $T$ is invertible, note that $S = (ST)T^{-1}$.